# How does the Intermediate Value Theorem prove change of sign at discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I understand how the Intermediate Value Theorem proves a sign change can only happen at roots if a function is continuous. Intuitively, I understand the possible sign change due to a discontinuity.  However, I don't understand how the theorem proves a sign change can happen at a discontinuity when the theorem only applies to continuous functions. Or is that the reason that the theorem only applies to continuous functions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "a sign change can only happen at roots"?

Comment: A function can only change sign at roots, or x-intercepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation of that statement is that, when $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$ and $f$ does not have a root (in $(a,b)$), then $f$ is not continuous on $[a,b]$, i.e. there exists at least one point in that interval where $f$ is not continuous.